# ¿Se puede bloquear un archivo de un repositorio mientras lo modifico en Visual Studio?

Tags: git, repositorio

Tengo un repositorio local en mi servidor en el cual tengo una solución de un sitio de `asp.net`.
Lo que necesito saber es si hay forma de "bloquear" alguna clase que yo esté usando para que las personas que también trabajan en este proyecto no puedan modificarlo hasta que yo termine con mis cambios.

**Ejemplo:**
Supongamos que tengo el `LogIn.aspx.cs` en el que tengo que cambiar la forma en la que valida la pass. Lo que quiero yo es bloquear ese `LogIn.aspx.cs` para que nadie más pueda modificarlo y sincronizarlo en el repositorio hasta que yo termine de hacer mis cambios.

¿Eso es posible o no?
De ser posible ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: tecnicamente no deberias tener problemas, deberian haber diferentes ramas en desarrollo, luego haces un merge y todo deberia funcionar

Comment: Pero el merge me fusiona las dos clases modificadas o es para que yo agregue lo modificado por el otro desarrollador?

Comment: el merge fuciona dos ramas que pueden haber sido modificada por N personas

Comment: No es posible, porque no es la idea con la que nació git. Su propósito es permitir que   múltiples personas trabajen sobre un mismo proyecto de la forma mas ágil posible, ya que tu requerimiento no debe ser el mismo que el de tus compañeros por lo que no deberían cruzar código que afecte el `merge`, la forma básica es hacer una rama donde apliques tus cambios evitando que otros modifiquen tu código. Una solución para tu caso esto es utilizar metodología scrum para listar todos los cambios que se realizaran y de esta forma controlar el flujo de cambios del día.